# ¿Existe una forma de curvar un elemento html con css o js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estaba intentando hacer el efecto de una tarjeta al tomarla del mazo, e intentaba hacerlo li más realizar posible, pero después de muchos intentos no logro hacer el efecto que quería, una especie de curvatura en la tarjeta, como si fuese una lamina, solo conseguí cambiar la perspectiva en z, todo esto solo con css, y como no me se un termino para ese tipo de animación todas mis búsquedas terminan en la misma animación que ya tengo. un ejemplo de como queda la tarjeta.

```css
.carta-box {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 128.4px;
  height: 187.2px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}

.carta-box:hover .carta {
  animation: flip linear .5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.carta {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-animation: unflip .5s reverse;
}

.cara {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.cara, img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cara.detras {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

@keyframes flip{
  0%{ transform: translateX(0) rotateY(0deg); z-index: 5;}
  50%{ transform: translateX(-10%) translateY(50px) rotateY(95deg) rotateZ(-20deg) scale(1.3,1.3); z-index: 5;}
  100%{ transform: translateX(0) translateY(0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1,1); z-index: 5;}
}

@keyframes unflip{
  0%{ transform: translateX(0) rotateY(0deg); z-index: 5;}
  50%{ transform: translateX(-10%) translateY(50px) rotateY(95deg) rotateZ(-20deg) scale(1.3,1.3); z-index: 5;}
  100%{ transform: translateX(0) translateY(0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1,1); z-index: 5;}
}
```

```html
<div class="carta-box" >
        <div class="carta" id="test">    
            <div class="cara detras">
                <img src="https://solitarios-online.com/media/cards/2h.png" draggable="false">
            </div>
            <div class="cara">
                    <img src="https://static7.depositphotos.com/1257959/746/v/950/depositphotos_7461811-stock-illustration-playing-card-back-side-60x90.jpg" draggable="false">
            </div>    
        </div>
</div>
```

Y una pequeña ilustración de lo que quería y más o menos como me queda, lo que consigo lo siento muy rígido, me gustaría algo que se viera algo más fluido, algo así como en la vida real.
[image: Al voltearla]
[image: Al voltearla]
[image: Al sacarla del mazo]
[image: Al sacarla del mazo]

Comment: No se si es útil, pero talvez skew te pueda ayudar https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew()

Comment: Lastimosamente no me funciono, pero gracias por la información, talvez no me funciona para lo que quería pero le puedo encontrar utilidad de otra manera, muchas gracias.

Comment: Encontré esto, https://cssdeck.com/labs/wrap-image-in-3d-cylinder-2, parece que es la mejor forma de hacerlo con css, así que creo que tendré que recurrir a js para hacer lo que tengo pensado, algo así como los efectos de páginas de libros.

Comment: Encontré esto que tiene un efecto de pagina de libro y tiene algo parecido a lo que buscas, te lo dejo por si acaso https://codepen.io/ryrocks/pen/zovXWy?editors=1100 mucha suerte!

Comment: Estoy probándolo, no quedaría como pensaba, pero creo que puede funcionar, pero me tomare una pausa para relajarme, igual muchas gracias.